# What's the name of the Shorin Ryu technique that's most like upward palm block?

Tags: tae-kwon-do, karate

I'm asking because I noticed this technique in Wu Mei that looks exactly like it.
I'd like to see the Shorin bunkai for this technique.

https://youtu.be/Qwhqp0eJhDw?t=1115

Comment: I think the reason why you're not getting any answers here is because you haven't specified the shorin-ryu kata that has this technique. There are a number of candidates that are similar. As with all kata bunkai, you do need to look at the movement within the context of the form to be able to get a hint at what its purpose actually was/is.

Comment: Ahh..I don't know the Shorin kata. I practice ITF TaeKwon-Do. But, i'll look through the Shotokan Kata and try to find an applicable candidate technique.

Comment: If you don't want to limit it to just Shorin-ryu, you might extend it to all Okinawan karate as well. But I suppose you're interested in Shorin-ryu in particular, because your Taekwondo has roots in that. You could point out the movement in your Taekwondo hyung as well.

Comment: It's this technique https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAry_mw9Mvo

Comment: It's this technique https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAry_mw9Mvo  It's the third and sixth movement from, Joong -Gun tul, this pattern https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBMXzIt1NFU. Here's GM Nardizzi doing Joong Gun, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypbA4Xx2SfE